# Limit Android apk download to ARM devices

Tags: android, arm, google-play

I have an App containing a native library. The library only works in Android devices containing an ARM cpu.
The native library .so files are stored in the armeabi-v7a folder indicating the .so files are for a ARM cpu.

[image]

However when I upload the apk to the Play Store, the App can be downloaded on Android devices containing a x86 (or mips) based cpu. The App crashes as the library does not work on a non ARM cpu.
Unfortunately the library is only available on ARM so I can't include the x86 and mips .so files.

My question is: how can I limit the App from being downloaded by non ARM cpu devices?

I expected some requires=* settings in the AndroidManifest files but I can't find related settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to advanced mode in the Google Play Developer Console it should give you some options regarding limiting to specific CPU architectures when uploading your APK. Documentation can be found at http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html .